# On a Riemann surface, $p$ is a Weierstrass point iff the Wronskian verifies $W(0) = 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, wronskian

Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface. Let $\{h_1(z),\ldots,h_g(z)\}$ be a base of the space of holomorphic forms on $X$ in a local map centered in $p\in X$. I’d like to know how to show that $p$ is a [Weierstrass point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_point) iff the Wronskian

$$W(z):=\begin{vmatrix}h_1(z) & h_2(z) & \ldots & h_g(z) \\h_1’(z) & h_2’(z) & \ldots & h_g’(z) \\ \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\h_1^{(g-1)}(z) & h_2^{(g-1)}(z) & \ldots & h_g^{(g-1)}(z)\end{vmatrix}$$

verifies $W(0)=0$.

I honestly don’t really know how to tackle this problem. The only thing I could think of is trying to show that if $W(0)=0$ then all of the vectors $\{h_1^{(i)}(0), h_2^{(i)}(0), \ldots, h_g^{(i)}(z)\}$ (for $0\leq i \leq g-1$) lie in a $(g-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^g$, hoping that this could somehow be used to conclude that the functions $\{h_i\}$ are linearly dependent? Or in other words, that if $\{h_1(z),\ldots,h_g(z)\}$ are linearly independent holomorphic functions defined in a neighborhood of $z=0$, then $W(0) \neq 0$.

But the problem seems complicated to me and I don’t exactly see how this connects with Weierstrass points (if that’s of any use, I understand nearly everything on the Wikipedia article about them). Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I’m using the following definition of Weierstrass point: $p\in X$ is a Weierstrass point iff $\dim(L(g(p))) >1$.

Comment: Edit your post to include the precise definition of Weierstrass point you’re using.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I assumed all the definitions of Weierstrass point were immediately equivalent. I edited the post.

Comment: Explain more. What is $g(p)$, for starters?

Comment: @TedShifrin It’s the divisor $g.(p)$, where $p$ is a point of $X$ and $g$ is the genus of $X$. If I’m not mistaken, a point $p$ of $X$ is a Weierstrass point iff the Riemann-Roch space $L(g(p))$ has a nonconstant function on it, or equivalently, $\dim(L(g(p)))>1$… I think I understand that so far.

Comment: It's very hard to know what you know and what you don't. From the geometric interpretation of Riemann-Roch (relations on the canonical curve imposed by a divisor), this is quite immediate. See pp. 248-9 and 274 (middle paragraph) of Griffiths and Harris for a proof of this result.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I will try to clarify: I’ve taken a first course on Riemann Surfaces, I understand the basic version of the Riemann-Roch theorem and what a Weierstrass point is: I understand the definition and the explanation of the differences between Weierstrass and non-Weierstrass points as it is described on the Wikipedia article I linked, that is, how the sequence $\dim(L(k(p)))_k$ looks for a Weierstrass and non-Weierstrass point respectively. I don’t know anything about the geometric interpretation of Riemann-Roch though.

Comment: I also don’t know anything about linear systems in this context. I was consulting Miranda’s book on Riemann Surfaces to try to find more information on this topic, as the first half of this book was pretty close to what we’ve seen in the course, but linear systems weren’t even mentionned during the classes. This result was proposed as an exercise and we didn’t see anything related to how the Wronskian works in this context either, it was just defined for the purposes of this exercise as the determinant I wrote.

Comment: Of course the Wronskian is the determinant of this matrix. This is about the geometry of the canonical curve *at a point*; there is no relation with linear independence as you’re thinking. I believe you’re reading about the Wronskian in the context of solutions of a differential equation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, differential equations are the only context in which I’ve encountered the Wronskian previously, apart from that I just know the definition I gave in the question (I meant to write it as a determinant, sorry). We didn’t mention the canonical curve during the course, I’ll try to find information about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that we can organize the $h_i$ so that $\def\ord{\operatorname{ord}}\ord_p(h_i) < \ord_p(h_{i+1})$ for all $i$. First, pick $h_1$ to be a member of the $h_i$ so that $\ord_p(h_i)$ is minimal. Now for each $h_i$ with $\ord_p(h_1)=\ord_p(h_i)$, we can replace $h_i$ by $h_i+ch_1$ for some constant $c$ so that we still have a basis and $\ord_p(h_1)<\ord_p(h_i+ch_i)$: just cancel the lowest degree term in the local power series expansion. Repeating this process, we have the claim.

Now we can reduce the vanishing of the Wronskian to the existence of a Weierstrass point. The vector $(h_i(z),h_i'(z),\cdots,h_i^{(g-1)}(z))$ consists of $\ord_p(h_i)$ zeroes followed by a nonzero entry followed by arbitrary entries, so the Wronskian matrix is lower-triangular and thus the determinant is the product of the diagonal entries. Further, if there's a zero on the diagonal, then all entries on the diagonal which are below and to the right of that zero must be zero as well, so the determinant of the Wronskian matrix is zero iff $h_g$ is of order at least $g$ at $p$. Such a function will demonstrate that we have $l(gp)>1$: by Riemann-Roch, $l(gp)-l(K-gp)=1$, and $\ord_p(h_g)\geq g$ implies $l(K-gp)\geq 0$, so $l(gp)>1$ and we're done.